# "That's much too late!"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-order

> MUM: What time did you come home last night?
>
> ANNE: Oh, about 3 o'clock.
>
> MUM: What! That's **much too** late!

First, Why does she use *much too*, not *too much*? Can we replace *much too*, with *too much*. 
Second, what is the difference between them.

I read the answers of the following questions but I don't know if these expressions are interchangeable or not:

- [“much too [something]” vs “too much [something]”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104388/much-too-something-vs-too-much-something)
- [“Too much” versus “much too”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69098/too-much-versus-much-too)

**Update:**

is the following incorrect?

> What! That's **too much** late!

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104388/much-too-something-vs-too-much-something

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, you want "much too" here. As was said in the ELU question @AhmbroDude linked to:

> *Too much* modifies a noun and a verb, and *much too* modifies an adjective or adverb. ([source](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104390))

---

To elaborate on this a little, notice that you can't put *much* directly before an adjective or adverb, except in the comparative form:

> ✗ That dog is **much scary**.
>   
> <sub>✓ That dog is **much scarier** than this one.</sub>
>
> ✗ He arrived **much late**.
>   
> <sub>✓ She arrived **much later** than he did.</sub>
>
> ✗ The film adaptation was made **much quickly**.
>   
> <sub>✓ The film adaptation was made **much more quickly** than the graphic novel adaptation.</sub>

This alone should tell us that "too **much late**" doesn't work.<sup>1</sup>

---

On the other hand, you can say *too* before an adjective or adverb:

> ✓ That dog is **too** scary.
>
> ✓ He arrived **too** late.
>
> ✓ The film adaptation was made **too** quickly.

---

Finally, *much* can come before *too*. If it does, not only does it mean "more than acceptable", but "a lot more than acceptable".

> ✓ That dog is **much too** scary.
>
> ✓ He arrived **much too** late.
>
> ✓ The film adaptation was made **much too** quickly.

---

<sup>1 Although the comparative does:</sup>

> <sup>The remake was made later than the original.</sup>
>   
> <sup>The remake was made **too much later** than the original for the cultural references to make sense.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

*Much* is a weird word, it can be a determiner, pronoun, or adverb.

When *much* is used as a determiner, like an article or a possessive like *my*, *his*, etc. what follows has to be a noun.

So if you immediately follow *much* with an adjective, it's possible to come across as though you are trying to use the adjective as a noun.

So:

> I am much too late. (Another adverb follows *much* so it's obvious you are using it as an adverb.)
>
> *I am too much late. (*Late* is an adjective, not a noun.)